# script inside jquery mobile collapsible fire twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Why does this script in jQuery mobile collapsible fire twice?

Update:The code show that when click "btnonce" only 1 alert, but "btntwice" 2 alert, only different is "btntwice" javascript under "div data-role="collapsible" , why it fire twice?

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
   <div data-role="content"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#page').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    $("#btnonce").click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
 })
</script>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="one">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#page').live('pageinit', function (event) {
      $("#btntwice").click(function() {
      alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
   })
</script>
 <h3>Test</h3>
<input type="button" id="btntwice" data-icon="check" value="fire twice" ></input>
<input type="button" id="btnonce" data-icon="check" value="fire once" ></input>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8PM2/39/

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript to this :

```
$('#page').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    $("#btnonce").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
    $("#btntwice").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
})
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/M8PM2/40/)

Your `click` handler was being added twice - [see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/M8PM2/42/)

Comment: thanks ManseUK, but just like your "see this example", why it being added twice (alert('Called');)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the way the jqm collapsible _create function uses jQuery wrapInner(). There is a known jQuery bug (or is it a feature?) whereby script tags inside content which is to be wrapped is re-executed by the domManip logic. Good times.

If you can move the script out of the collapsible, that would be ideal. You might could hack jqm to not use wrapInner for that particular line of code:

```
collapsibleContent = collapsible.wrapInner( "<div class='ui-collapsible-content'></div>" ).children( ".ui-collapsible-content" ),
```

Personally, I'm going to go with an old school "if (alreadyRan) return; alreadyRan = true;"-type flag. Makes me nostalgic for FORTRAN.

**Update**

So I ended up going with the following in my jqm setup script (to be run on every page and "sub" page):

```
$(document).on({
    pagecreate: function (e) {
        $(':jqmData(role=collapsible) script').remove();
    }
}, ':jqmData(role=page)');
```

Seems harmless enough. I can always add a class to my script and modify the selector if for some reason I **do** want to run inline scripts twice. Something like:

```
$(':jqmData(role=collapsible) script:not(.do-not-remove)').remove();
```